# Polymer paper-ripple and on-mouseover

Tags: polymer

I am trying to implement my own custom tooltip element, which displays the tooltip when the on-mouseover event is fired. However, this does not work:

```
<div class="message>
    <custom-tooltip text="{{time}}">
        <div>{{message}}</div>
    </custom-tooltip>
    <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
</div>
```

because the paper-ripple is "above" the custom-tooltip and therefore not passing on any of its events. I'm not sure if this is a polymer specific issue, or if it just my inexperience with DOM event propagation, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you set up a jsbin that shows the problem? It would help for folks to see exactly what you're talking about, and it makes it much easier to debug.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please share what you did.